# In webhdfs, what is the difference between length and spaceConsumed?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

Using [webhdfs we can get the content summary of a directory/file.](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#ContentSummary)

However, the following properties are unclear for me:

```
"length":
        {
          "description": "The number of bytes used by the content.",
          "type"       : "integer",
          "required"   : true
        }


"spaceConsumed":
        {
          "description": "The disk space consumed by the content.",
          "type"       : "integer",
          "required"   : true
        }
```

What exactly is the difference between those ? Is `spaceConsumed` the size taken on disk duplication included ? The internal [method documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/ContentSummary.html#getSpaceConsumed()) does not provide additional detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a collegue, the answer is:

```
spaceConsumed = length * replicationFactor
```

However, I have no source to prove it.

Comment: Hadoop is open source if you really wanted to look at the value definitions